# How to cast QVariant to custom class?

Tags: c++, linux, qt, casting

I have a QVariant object within a QTreeWidgetItem, how can I cast it to my own object?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

you need to declare somewhere in an `.h` file the following:

```
Q_DECLARE_METATYPE(MyStruct)
```

and then you can just use:

```
MyStruct s;
QVariant var;
var.setValue(s); // copy s into the variant

// retrieve the value
MyStruct s2 = var.value<MyStruct>();
```

[see the docs here](http://doc.trolltech.com/4.3/qmetatype.html)

Comment: Does the Q_DECLARE_METATYPE have to be outside class/namespace definition?